# Dgrid preforming update on a data source with one colum

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I have a dgrid which only has one column of data *(name)* however i am attempting to preform an update on this column and it keeps inserting a new record. I understand it will treat the information entered as a new record since the *idProperty* in the dgrid is = *name*. How can i over come this issue and be able to update the selected column without preforming a new update.

I also understand dgrid does not implement the concept of a row index. Under is my code:

**Dgrid**

```
var nameStore = new dojo.store.Observable(new Memory({data: data, idProperty:"name"}));

var nameGrid = new CustomNameGrid ({
          store: nameStore,
            columns: {

                chkBox:selector({}),

                Name:{
                    label:"Names",
                    field:"name"
                }

            } ,
            selectionMode:"none",
            loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
            noDataMessage: "No results found....",
            allowSelectAll: true
        }, "nameGrid");
```

**Data**

```
var data = [{name:"ABC"},
             { name:"DEFG"},
             { name:"HIJK LMNOP"}];
```

**Update Function**

Once the update button is clicked an update function is fired, the function works excepts it inserts a new row instead of updating the selected row. The main statement in the update function is

```
var userEnteredName = document.getElementById('nameEntered').value

aliasStore.put({name:userEnteredName});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `id` field to your data and remove the `idProperty` from your Memory store or set it to "id".  When you want to update a row, use the id from the selected row and set `name` to the new value.

```
nameStore.put({id:selectedRowId, name: userEnteredName});
```

Life is better when you generate primary keys rather than use business data because you run into problems when that business data needs to change.

Comment: I agree that its good practice to use some unique key to identify the data items in the `Memory` store based on non business logic. However simple tests putting and getting data using the "name" as `idProperty` do correctly update, so I think this needs more investigation.

Comment: If I have an object with id "foo", the `put` method does not have a way for me to change that id to "bar".  In this example, when I set `object['name'] = 'bar'`, I have changed the identity of that object.  There is no way to tell `put` that this object with `name` set to "bar" is the same object still in the store that has `name` set to "foo".

Comment: If your `idProperty` is set to "name" and you `put({name: "jon"})` then do another `put({name: "jon"})` only 1 object exists in the memory store, it may be a different object, but it has effectively updated not added to the store.

Answer (score 1):

Its worth (if you are using a [Memory store](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/store/Memory) to back your dgrid data) checking the put directives being used when you perform an update on an existing row, check the [Dojo PutDirectives API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/store/api/Store.PutDirectives) for details.

Maybe you need to set `overwrite` to true when doing the `put()`?